# Merging 2 data frames with placeholders in multiple positions in df1, and placeholders filled in df2

Tags: r, regex, merge

I have two data frames; (**DF 1**) that has rows with both variables that have "wildcards" in different locations of the string as well as variables with no "wildcards", and (**DF 2**) that has multiple rows with variables from DF 1 but the "wildcard" filled in.

**DF 1**

```
Wild_Cards<-data.frame(Var=c("Var A[*]","Var B[*, X1]","Var C[X2, *]","Var D[*, *]", "Var E"),A=c(1,0.5,0.8,0,-1),B=c(2,1.5,1.8,1,0))

           Var    A   B
1     Var A[*]  1.0 2.0
2 Var B[*, X1]  0.5 1.5
3 Var C[X2, *]  0.8 1.8
4  Var D[*, *]  0.0 1.0
5        Var E -1.0 0.0
```

**DF 2**

```
Values<-data.frame(Var=c("Var A[Y]","Var A[Z]","Var B[Y, X1]","Var B[Z, X1]","Var C[X2, Y]", "Var C[X2, Z]","Var D[A, Y]","Var D[B, Z]", "Var E"), D=c(1.5,1.8,1,1.4,1,1,0,0.5,-0.5))


           Var    D
1     Var A[Y]  1.5
2     Var A[Z]  1.8
3 Var B[Y, X1]  1.0
4 Var B[Z, X1]  1.4
5 Var C[X2, Y]  1.0
6 Var C[X2, Z]  1.0
7  Var D[A, Y]  0.0
8  Var D[B, Z]  0.5
9        Var E -0.5
```

I need to combine these data frames so that the relevant `A` and `B` values are merged by matching DF 1's variable namess with wildcards to DF 2's variables names.

It is important that the final result maintains the variable name format.

**Desired Output**

```
Result<-data.frame(Var=c("Var A[Y]","Var A[Z]","Var B[Y, X1]","Var B[Z, X1]","Var C[X2, Y]", "Var C[X2, Z]","Var D[A, Y]","Var D[B, Z]", "Var E"), D=c(1.5,1.8,1,1.4,1,1,0,0.5,-0.5),A=c(1,1,0.5,0.5,0.8,0.8,0,0,-1),B=c(2,2,1.5,1.5,1.8,1.8,1,1,0))

           Var    D    A   B
1     Var A[Y]  1.5  1.0 2.0
2     Var A[Z]  1.8  1.0 2.0
3 Var B[Y, X1]  1.0  0.5 1.5
4 Var B[Z, X1]  1.4  0.5 1.5
5 Var C[X2, Y]  1.0  0.8 1.8
6 Var C[X2, Z]  1.0  0.8 1.8
7  Var D[A, Y]  0.0  0.0 1.0
8  Var D[B, Z]  0.5  0.0 1.0
9        Var E -0.5 -1.0 0.0
```

I've attempted to break this down and accomplish it in small steps with `stringr` `fuzzyjoin`'s `regex_join`, but haven't been able to get anywhere near the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a combination of `utils::glob2rz` and `fuzzyjoin::regex_*_join`:

`fuzzyjoin::regex_*_join` requires true-regex patterns, but your patterns appear to be more "glob"-style wildcards. Luckily, we can easily convert from the latter to the former in base R:

```r
glob2rx(Wild_Cards$Var)
# [1] "^Var A\\[.*]$"     "^Var B\\[.*, X1]$" "^Var C\\[X2, .*]$" "^Var D\\[.*, .*]$" "^Var E$"          
Wild_Cards$ptn <- glob2rx(Wild_Cards$Var)
```

From here, it's just a regex join:

```r
fuzzyjoin::regex_right_join(Values, Wild_Cards, by = c(Var = "ptn"))
#          Var.x    D        Var.y    A   B               ptn
# 1     Var A[Y]  1.5     Var A[*]  1.0 2.0     ^Var A\\[.*]$
# 2     Var A[Z]  1.8     Var A[*]  1.0 2.0     ^Var A\\[.*]$
# 3 Var B[Y, X1]  1.0 Var B[*, X1]  0.5 1.5 ^Var B\\[.*, X1]$
# 4 Var B[Z, X1]  1.4 Var B[*, X1]  0.5 1.5 ^Var B\\[.*, X1]$
# 5 Var C[X2, Y]  1.0 Var C[X2, *]  0.8 1.8 ^Var C\\[X2, .*]$
# 6 Var C[X2, Z]  1.0 Var C[X2, *]  0.8 1.8 ^Var C\\[X2, .*]$
# 7  Var D[A, Y]  0.0  Var D[*, *]  0.0 1.0 ^Var D\\[.*, .*]$
# 8  Var D[B, Z]  0.5  Var D[*, *]  0.0 1.0 ^Var D\\[.*, .*]$
# 9        Var E -0.5        Var E -1.0 0.0           ^Var E$
```

With some cleanup required with column names and such.

Comment: Thanks very much, r2evans. This was exactly what I was looking for.

I was not aware of the distinction between glob-style wildcards vs true-regex. That makes much more sense now. Thank's for expanding my knowledge.

Comment: With regex comes a lot of "power" ... and many-times-more the opportunity to munge things horribly. Glad it helped.